# Check width of TextBlock after content changed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some `TextBlock`, that can display very long string.

However, when `TextBlock` *content* `width` become greater than `TextBlock` own `width`, i want to cut some part of content and place "..." at the end instead.

I will display full content as `TooTtip`.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyValue}" TextAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" ToolTip="{Binding MyValue}" />
```

As far as i know TextBlock have no events, that can fire after content changed. Is there any good approach to listen something like `contentChanged` event on TextBlock, calculate text width, compare with control width and cut part of content that not fit?

I need to do it in codebehind, because viewmodel cant be changed some reasons that not matter.

Comment: Why not just set `TextTrimming` no either `CharacterEllipsis` or `WordEllipsis`?

Comment: You can write a converter which would contain that logic and pass right data to TextBlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TextTrimming:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming(v=vs.110).aspx

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyValue}" 
TextAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" 
ToolTip="{Binding MyValue}" 
TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
```

or you can set it in codebehind:

```
myTextBlock.TextTrimming = TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis;
```